# jQuery 2 error messages being returned but only need 1 to display

Tags: jquery

Ok I have 2 error messages being return which in turn displays 2 messages of the same thing. how can I only show one message?

```
jQuery.noConflict();

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      if (jQuery("span.errorMessage").length > 0) {                                                              
         var $this = jQuery("span.errorMessage");
         var t = $this.text();

         // Clear the text
         $this.text('');

         // Add new message
         $this.text('No search criteria was specified.');

         // Change the layout
         jQuery('#errorMessage').appendTo(jQuery('#message_display'));
      }
   });
```

Adding the HTML for the error's

```
<span id="errorMessage">    
         <ul>
        <li><span class="errorMessage">No search criteria was specified.</span></li>
        <li><span class="errorMessage">No search criteria was specified.</span></li>
    </ul>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are appending the text to #errormessage, but clearing out #this.text().  I'm guessing that you are needing to clear the #errormessage before adding new errors to it.

Try This....

```
<div id="errorMessage">    
    <ul>
        <li><span class="errorMessage">1 No search criteria was specified.</span></li>
        <li><span class="errorMessage">2 No search criteria was specified.</span></li>
        <li><span class="errorMessage">3 No search criteria was specified.</span></li>
        <li><span class="errorMessage">4 No search criteria was specified.</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    SetupMessageManager();
    $('.errorMessage').parent().hide();
    $('.errorMessage:first').parent().show();
});
```

Comment: Yes it's passing LOG info but I just need a generic error message

Comment: Also the error messages are passed back on a UL, each message is a LI

Comment: oh ok...  so you have a list of errors (#message_display) and there is a duplicate message within the list?

Comment: does the validation duplicate the message on the first pass, or does it only do it on the second, and each one there after?  So after 3 button clicks, you have 3 messages?

Comment: the script is passing 2 error messages back one one submit call, but I only need one message to display

Comment: if there are more than 1 message it always comes as a LI in the UL, but regardless of the amount I only need one to display

Comment: If you only want 1 message at any time, you should clear the UL of messages before adding a new one.